# How to call Private function form static function in PHP class

Tags: php

I am getting an error when trying to do this.
Here is how the class looks like:

```
class Users
{
    private function mysql_query_excute( $sql )
{
    ... do something here ...
    return $result;
}
    public static function Find_user( $provider, $provider_uid )
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE provider = '$provider' 
                              AND provider_uid = '$provider_uid' 
                              LIMIT 1";
    $result = Users::mysql_query_excute($sql);
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

The error I get "Find_user" function is:

```
Non-static method Users::mysql_query_excute() should not be called statically
```

Can someone tell me how can I solve this?
I looked around other similar questions and the solution provided were similar to what I am doing, so not sure whats going wrong here :(

Thanks

Comment: I think the error message is crystal-clear... Your `mysql_query_excute` is not static, so don't call it statically...

Comment: static functions exist "on the class", and your private function exists "on individual objects". Unless you first build an instance in your static function, there is nothing on which you can even call `mysql_query_excute`

Comment: As a secondary comment: `mysql_...` has been removed from PHP. It's not just deprecated, it's been ripped out, because it was so bad. The new api is the `mysqli_...` set of functions (which has different argument ordering so you can't just rename mysql to mysqli. Thankfully). Even if you solve the static/private issue, your code likely won't run on a new version of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a non-static function in a static way.

Change:

```
private function mysql_query_excute( $sql )
```

to:

```
static private function mysql_query_excute( $sql )
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your mysql_query_execute

```
private static function mysql_query_execute( $sql );
```